# removing the value from a object in java or android

Tags: java, android, hashmap

```
private String[] userKeys;

userKeys =  MHConstants.friendsModelDetails.keySet().toArray( new String[MHConstants.friendsModelDetails.size()]);

if(MHConstants.friendsModelDetails.size()>0 ){
        for(int i = 0;i<MHConstants.friendsModelDetails.size();i++){
            String username = userKeys[i];

System.out.println("userkey contains"+username);
}
String number=9;
```

THis prints
1
5
9
8
10

How can i get the position of  the value which is equal to ''number'' and delete that from userskey...
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try  Apache Commons

```
userKeys = ArrayUtils.removeElement(userKeys , number);
```

Or just iterating through array and shifting elements can do the same.
Something like  (Its ugly and not tried/tested)

```
String number = "9";
boolean flag = false;
int j;
int length = userKeys.length;
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if(number.equals(userKeys[i])){
        flag = true;
        j = i;
    }
}
if(flag){
    for(int i=j;i<length-1;i++){
        userKeys[i+1] = userKeys[i];
    }
    userKeys[length] = null; // resetting the value
}
```

Comment: don't forget to do `userKeys = removeElement(userKey...`

Comment: @JohnB..thanks for your reply..for userKeys = removeElement(userKey...      its giving error on ArrayUtils and its not let me importing the ArrayUtils . the second prat of code is giving error on userKeys[length] = 0; line(Type Mismatch can not convert int to string)

Comment: @Alpesh: I have updated my answer. That was just a example to give a idea.

Comment: @Karna..can you vote for this question please..so that my reputation could be 20 and i could be able to chat..

Comment: @Tupac Assuming you mean accepted, only OP can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `List` instead of an `Array`. Then use an `Iterator` which will allow you to remove the element.

```
List<String> values = ...;
Iterator<String> iterator = values.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext){
      String next = iterator.next();
      if (number.equals(next))
         iterator.remove();
}
```

Comment: WHen i am defining the List<String>usersKey   then its giving me erroe at a lot of places .can you please suggest me something simple..same as userKeys = ArrayUtils.removeElement(userKeys , number); and why the its not allowing me to importing the  ArrayUtils??